# ssh connection times out

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall

I have 2 Ubuntu servers that I access via their IP addresses, which are named bris (running Ubuntu 14.04) and syd (running Ubuntu 18.04).

When trying to connect from syd to bris I get:

```
root@prod:~# ssh root@bris -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "bris" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bris [bris] port 22.
```

which times out. I can't connect with telnet either.

the bris VPS has a firewall in its config panel where the IP address for syd is allowed on port 22. All other IPs are denied.

bris has:

- no entries in /etc/hosts.deny
- is listening on port 22
- has nothing configured in /etc/ssh/sshd_config that could cause an issue

syd has:

- ufw status = inactive

Can anyone help me troubleshoot the connection issue between syd to bris?

Comment: What says: `nmap -p '22' bris` , if you execute it on syd?

Comment: Not an answer but you can also try SSH agent forwarding (`ssh -A username@syd`, then try connecting to bris) as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this to help others.

Turned out i had a copy-paste error in the mPanel firewall rules on Syd. that were causing the issue.